# Populating listbox in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I´m trying to populate a listbox in excel with values from a range (column). I´m using  basically exact  code from a tutorial video on the subject but mine isn`t working.

Code:

```
Private Sub PopList()

   MTools.List = SheetDATA.Range("A2", SheetDATA.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value

End Sub
```

"MTools" is the name of the listbox, "SheetDATA" is the (code)name of the worksheet.

There is no error message, just nothing happens..

Comment: I would suggest you double check your Sheet name as well as your Listbox name, the code as it stands works for me. Might be worth qualifying/specifying the Listbox with the UserForm name in case you have more than one UserForm, something like `UserForm1.MTools.List = ...`

Comment: How are you calling `PopList`? You might need to share more of the form's Modules.

Comment: Just try - `SheetDATA.Range("A2", SheetDATA.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select`  to see what the real range is.

Comment: The range seems to be fine but still for some reason it does not work. Tried all the suggestions but still no sucess.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the sub callout as CLR suggested. I`m a complete beginner and in programming so yeah it don`t know how should it be properly called out..

Answer (score 1):

It works, when you declare the listbox as a variable:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
    Set lb = Worksheets(1).ListBox1
    lb.List = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A5").Value2

End Sub
```